# Button styling gives weird results

Tags: java, android, android-button, android-styles

I have a simple Button style, like

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

at this point the output is as this

[image]

it seems that the style is not applied and the colors are not set correctly.    When I change the style to something like this

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

I get something like this

[image]

Thw Button looks insane, but the style is applied.
How can I retain the Button shape as shiwn in the first picture and apply my styles correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've found a way to get the Job done quite promisingly

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_ripple</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">88dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">36dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">3dp</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:translationZ">1dp</item>
    </style>
```

and last the btn_ripple.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/btn_press">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

and the result is

[image]

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be located in the parent.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
```

I belive the second snippet sets the button style, overriding the parent. Try to remove the parent, and see what happens.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```